# How to set value in JObject using dynamic JSonPath query?

Tags: c#, json, jsonpath

The following code returns the expected json.

Code:

```
JToken fakeTarget = wrapper.Context.SelectToken("$.data");
```

Returns

```
{
  "mom": "",
  "dad": "",
  "sibling": "",
  "cousin": "",
  "calculated": ""
}
```

The following line of code accomplishes what I need to do, except for the below caveat:

```
wrapper.Context["data"]["calculated"] = "500";
```

Instead of explicitly providing the path like that, I need to provide it dynamically, something like this, but the syntax isn't right:

```
var path = "$.data.calculated";
wrapper.Context.SelectToken(path).Value = "500";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  Yuck.  Had to create an object (valueObject below) to get a JToken from to replace the existing one.  At least it works.  Note that JToken.IsNull() throws a not implemented exception, thus the target != null.  Real nice.

```
            var valueObject = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                value = "500"
            });

            JToken target = wrapper.Context.SelectToken(path);
            if (target != null)
            {
                JToken replacement = valueObject.SelectToken("value");
                target.Replace(replacement);
            }
```